# mysql update query from another table

Tags: mysql

I want to update some fields in my products table from a temporary table called updated table.

So far I have this, but I have an sql error, I cant find what it is yet though.

```
UPDATE destination 

SET destination.title = source.title, 
destination.title_tag = source.title_tag,
destination.keywords = source.keywords

FROM updated_table AS source

JOIN products AS destination ON source.id = destination.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE products AS destination
JOIN updated_table AS source
ON source.id = destination.id
SET destination.title = source.title, 
destination.title_tag = source.title_tag,
destination.keywords = source.keywords
```

Answer (score 0):

ANSI solution:

```
UPDATE
 products destination
SET
 destination.title = (SELECT title FROM updated_table source WHERE destination.id = source.id),
 destination.title_tag = (SELECT title_tag FROM updated_table source WHERE destination.id = source.id),
 destination.keywords = (SELECT keywords FROM updated_table source WHERE destination.id = source.id)
```

MySQL solution:

```
UPDATE
 products destination
JOIN
 updated_table source
ON
 source.id = destination.id
SET
 destination.title = source.title, 
 destination.title_tag = source.title_tag,
 destination.keywords = source.keywords
```

*If you are working on replication mysql servers, beware of prediction errors on combined updates.*

Answer (score 0):

Quicker version :

```
UPDATE destination AS source, products AS destination
SET destination.title = source.title, 
destination.title_tag = source.title_tag,
destination.keywords = source.keywords
where source.id = destination.id
```

Comment: what error? I dont have schema, so could You provide some extra info ?

Answer (score -1):

there is some problem with your query . try following query  :

```
UPDATE destination 

SET title = source.title, 
title_tag = source.title_tag,
keywords = source.keywords

FROM updated_table AS source

JOIN products AS destination ON source.id = destination.id
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, Syntax of Update is,

```
UPDATE tablename SET columnname=value WHERE condition;
```

not

```
UPDATE tablename SET columnname=value FROM something;
```

Rather try,

```
UPDATE products AS destination JOIN updated_table AS source 
ON source.id = destination.id
SET destination.title = source.title, 
destination.title_tag = source.title_tag,
destination.keywords = source.keywords
```

or

```
UPDATE products AS destination, updated_table AS source 
SET destination.title = source.title, 
destination.title_tag = source.title_tag,
destination.keywords = source.keywords 
WHERE source.id = destination.id
```